# Override Spring Data Elastic Search cluster node configuration

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm using Elastic Search for my project activities in which I communicated to the backend ES cluster through the spring utility

> spring-data-elastic-search

Following are the spring-repository descriptions for the webapp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-nodes="localhost:9300" />

    <bean name="elasticsearchTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client" />
    </bean>

    <elasticsearch:repositories
        base-package="com.customer.repositories" />
</beans>
```

Here I've specified the cluster node configuration as **cluster-nodes="localhost:9300"** and it is working fine with my local testing.

In production server we've a full functional cluster setup with host IP say (192.xx.xx.xx). So my problem is that, we have specified the cluster host in a yml file in /etc/project/es.yml file in the production server. So I need to tweak my application to take the cluster configuration from this custom location.

Since the above spring-repository xml initialized by the spring container, we are unable to override the behaviour. Is there any way to achieve it with spring-data-elastic-search ?

Comment: hey, spring data or elastic search experts any solutions for this issue ?

Comment: Any inputs spring guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved my issue and sharing it here, so that it may be useful to some one else.

Changed YML idea to property file (es.props)

spring repository descriptions should be as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>co
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch-1.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="file:/etc/project/es.props" />

    <elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-nodes="${es-host}:9300""/>

    <bean name="elasticsearchTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client" />
    </bean>

    <elasticsearch:repositories
        base-package="com.customer.repositories" />

</beans>
```

Which used Spring PropertySourcePlaceHolder modification mechanism in 3.1+.

So it will look up for es.host in /etc/project/es.props. Local testers can override this property by starting the server with -Des.host=custom-cluser-host

Actually [Mohsin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841614/mohsin-husen)(Spring-data-elastic-search developer) gave hints to arrive at this solution. Thanks Mohsin.